# User role Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a service with these methods:

```
Observable<User> getUsers();
Observable<Role> getUserRoles(String userId);
```

For each user, I want to get her roles and set them.

I have this method working:

```
private Observable<User> getUsersWithRoles() {
        return service.getUsers().flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<User>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<User> call(User user) {
                return Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(user), service.getUserRoles(user).toList(), new Func2<User, List<Role>, User>() {
                    @Override
                    public User call(User user, List<Role> roles) {
                        user.setRoles(roles);
                        return user;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't like these parts so much:

- `Observable.just(user)`
- `service.getUserRoles(user).toList()`

Is there a cleaner way to build this Observable?

Comment: which rx-java version you are using?

Comment: Some more ways to create observable: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#create

Comment: any particular reason why you do not like it and wanted to change it?